# Emacs - Running current file in Python

Tags: python, emacs

I am using ELPY in emacs in Windows. How do I eval current file inside emacs using a Shortcut.

When I use **eval-buffer**.
I get below messages.

*Flymake unable to run without a buffer file name*

*Removed if **main** == '**main**' construct, use a prefix argument to evaluate.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a built in feature in emacs when working with the python (inferior) shell, to prevent people from running the whole script unintentionally, which is does by redefining (or removing) `__name__` before it runs.

Your script does send `__name__ = "__main__"` but it is overwritten, due to this 'safety feature'.

To execute as you wish, running it as **main**, use the key binding:

```
`C-u C-c C-c`
```

If you would like to remap this to be something quicker or more familiar, try something like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") (kbd "C-u C-c C-c"))
```

this was discussed in this thread [here](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/69), where there is also some related extra information.